# Change default User login text in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to change the default User Login text in Drupal to Client Login? I am not able to figure out which PHP file has this piece of text.

[image]

Can somebody let me know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your block listing page `admin/structure/block`, and click on Configure next to `User login` block. (Or go to `admin/structure/block/manage/user/login/configure` directly) and set the title you want from the field **Block title**.